# React Native's Animated.ScrollView is not allowing me to programmatically scroll to a certain position

Tags: react-native, scrollview

Prior to upgrading to the newest version of React-Native and Expo this code block was working. The version it was working on was  `"expo": "^32.0.0"`.

I was previously able to programmatically move a child of Animated.ScrollView and now I'm no longer able to do so. Here is my testing code block that I am testing.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Animated,
  TouchableOpacity,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView
} from 'react-native';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleMove = () => {
    this.scroller.getNode().scrollTo({
      x: 200,
      y: 0,
      animated: false
    });
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
        <Animated.ScrollView
          horizontal
          ref={scroller => {
            this.scroller = scroller;
          }}
        >
          <View
            style={{
              height: 100,
              width: 100,
              backgroundColor: 'red',
              margin: 5
            }}
          />
        </Animated.ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.handleMove}>
          <Text>Move</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {}
});
```

After upgrading the code block no longer works on the newest version. The current version I am testing on is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "^34.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-34.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.4"
  },
```

What is the correct way of doing this?

I added a snack to help illustrate my problem. '
https://snack.expo.io/@louis345/brave-banana

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue by adding a prop to the scrollView. 
`scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}`

Now everything works as it once was. I hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: By looking closer to your code i've noticed that you call `getNode()` on your ref. I did that and it's working now! This is strange though, i couldn't find it in the docs and i usually access my ref's functions without having to go through `getNode()`. Thanks for your answer though!

Comment: It actually even works without `scrollToOverflowEnabled={true}` on my side. Using expo 35.

Comment: The problem is that this solution works only on IOS... have any solution for Android ?

Comment: Your solution is application only for IOS

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get this working by using a simple setTimeout of 1 second.

Here's what my code looks like now:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  this.scrollView.scrollTo({
    x: DEVICE_WIDTH * current_index,
    y: 0,
    animated: false
  });
}, 1)
```

Similar to what Micheal suggested above, it's likely that this is caused by a mounting issue due to the deprecated componentWillMount in React which wasn't properly updated in ScrollView.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```js
<Animated.ScrollView // <-- Use the Animated ScrollView wrapper
  scrollEventThrottle={1} // <-- Use 1 here to make sure no events are ever missed
  onScroll={Animated.event(
    [
      {
        nativeEvent: {
          contentOffset: {x: 200,y: 0},
        },
      },
    ],
    {useNativeDriver: true}, // <-- Add this
  )}>
  {content}
</Animated.ScrollView>
```

Comment: How would I do this programmatically?

Comment: You can put what you want in the content

Comment: I just tried the solution and I'm unable to get the animation working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after upgrading from 0.57 to 0.60.

It seems like something has changed with the timing for mounting stuff (between RN versions). I will go through my code again (in a couple of days), as I suspect that I'm using some of the soon-to-be deprecated lifecycle functions. The fact that they are now considered "unsafe" to use might be due to some timing issues (wild guess).

I got my code to work by simply putting the scrollTo in a 100ms timeout. This indicates that the scrollview is not quite mounted at the first try. I'm actually fine with the timeout for my use case, but I want to solve this anyway because I don't like hacky solutions.

Comment: I will verify once I get home. Thanks.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I can get the ScrollView via its ref (so it's definitely mounted) but the scrollTo doesn't work after upgrading for some reason. Is there anything else you noticed that might fix this for you?